# PHP Fatal error: IMAP connection broken with hotmail

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I am developing a Laravel-5.4 application that connect to some outlook/Hotmail mailbox using imap. From time to time (about 30%) i get this error when i try to connect using:

```
 try {
            $imap_open = imap_open($this->imapPath . $this->folder, $this->username, $this->password, OP_READONLY) or die('Cannot connect to : ' . $this->imapPath . '   ' . imap_last_error());
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output = new ConsoleOutput();
            $output->writeln('Imap Connect Exception : ' . $e->getMessage());
     }
```

Note: imapPath and username and password are hard coded so they remain the same in every request.

The error is not catchable by try_catch, so it block my entire request.

The error i get is:

```
[Thu Apr 27 12:39:08 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException'
 with message 'Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errfl
g=2)' in Unknown:0
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handle
Error(8, 'Unknown: [CLOSE...', 'Unknown', 0, Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in Unknown on line 0
```

what i want is to catch this Exception or Error if that is possible so i can re-connect again to the mailbox when the connection is broken.

Comment: Have you tried changing your Exception to ErrorException as said in the error?

Comment: @JoffreyCarle not yet i will try it. but should i import a specific class ?

Comment: Check this repo: https://github.com/zalazdi/laravel-imap it might solve your problem by handling it in a better way than you're doing now I think ;)

Comment: @JoffreyCarle i already checked it. but it's not suitable for my needs. so i developed my own library that handle my needs but i still get this error in this line from time to time. by the way thanks.